# Would a Psycho Killer still get a high body count after 40 years in jail?

Tags: internal-consistency

Johnny Killspeople is a troubled person who likes to kill people with melee weapons. 40 years ago he went on a spree and brutally killed a lot of people in a small town. After a few incidents he was locked up for life in a mental institution.

Though there have been a couple of incidents during his isolation (pretty rare occurences), meaning he fooled some guard and killed one or two people, he spent the great majority of this time behind bars.

---

Let's come back to the present. 40 years (of imprisonment) have passed. He must be about 60 to 70 years old now.

After killing a poor guard who was taking a nap, Mr. Killspeople escapes and heads straight to the little town of Manyvictims, where a townwide party is going on. He wants to start an even bigger spree in the little time he has left but... is it feasible?

Since he's WAY older, its safe to assume that his physical capabilites (reflexes, speed, stamina, strength) are not the same.

In this given scenario, would this guy still be able to get a high body count before he's dead/captured?

---

### Things to consider

If any other information is necessary I'll start editing this post and putting whatever is relevant here:

- As pointed by L.Dutch, I'm setting "high body count" as equal or more than 12 kills.

Comment: It really depends on how well Johnny kept himself while incarcerated, a really fit 60 year old is often in better shape than Joe Citizen, and that's determined by the story not set criteria.

Comment: I cast the final vote for OT:TSB.  Allow me to explain.  Worldbuilding (on-topic for this site) is about *systems* or, said another way, the rules of your world.  Storybuilding (off-topic for this site) is about *circumstances.*  This question is asking about *circumstances,* which is the danger when asking Qs about individuals (no matter how presented.)  This question would be on-topic had you asked, "what can a 65 y.o. do to have the strength and agility necessary to kill 12 people with a knife in less than 2 days?"  This makes the question objective and independent of the story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's also much wiser (well you know what I mean).

He don't mutilate the bodies. He kills than nice and clean leaving them in position typical for party goers: sleeping, drunk, pairs kissing in dim/dark.
Also a lot of police and people would be securing the party so that would leave other places almost empty and rarely visited.

So he could work from the fair working his way outside the town, roads would be empty so he could travel fast from place to place without alarming anyone about HIS particular existence.

12 people is easily achievable. I would say around 4 people on the fair (attendants), around 3 people working the backstage (as no one would notice if the guy watching cables is in the loo for too long), then few people around town in gas stations until he is bored and go back to fair.
By now they either:

- found the bodies and rise a silent alarm creating a little confusion. Police would figure out it's Johnny Killspeople so they would look form him. Johnny could use it to rise alarm and create panic to kill additional few people.
- The bodies are not yet been found to the fair is still going as it was. Johnny can go back to silently taking out people. Until he get's sloppy or would want to go full Machete in the crowd. Going Machete style is not a good way to kill many people. Rather injure.

Comment: I really liked your idea of leaving the bodies in "party position". This post was inspired by a movie I watched so your idea really gave me a "cinematographic" view while reading it.

Comment: @Magus also regarding Johnny age it would suit his ability to approach such people and kill. Drunk or sleeping wouldn't suspect older fellow. A kissing pair would be too occupied with each other to hear him approaching.

Comment: Yeah. The whole party idea was meant to try and make things a little easier towards the 12-people goal.

Answer (score 4):

## Its not hard to kill someone with a long knife

As long as he doesn't mind surprising people, it isn't that hard to kill someone with a long pointy weapon.

- Get someone alone, on a back street or a park at night.
- Make sure they aren't an athletic, sober young man (or woman)
- Stab to incapacitate
- Continue stabbing until dead
- Repeat

You'll probably get caught relatively soon, so the real question is if you can kill 12 people before the police nab you.

Comment: Good answer, although the entire town is in the middle of a party... does he really need to make sure there aren't athletic young people if most are potentially very drunk people?

Comment: There is always the edges of a party where people can be lured out and murdered without them or anyone noticing before its too late.

Comment: It is actually quite hard to kill someone, if you don't get them in the right place straight away there is a lot of noise and they fight back.... even if they die from loss of blood afterwards they can hurt you in the fight

Comment: @Kilisi Ol' Johnny sounds like he has a lot of experience

Comment: @kingledion no two victims or circumstances would be the same, I've survived knife attacks

Answer (score 1):

Johnny can also use a crowd as cover. In a similar way as with kingledion's answer the weapon should be something like a stiletto (or any knife or even a screwdriver will do). Move through the crowd, stabbing a target then walking (not running) away and repeating. Hide in the confusion and the crowds and attack whenever someone isn't looking his way.

Being old will actually work in his favour here if he plays into it and makes sure to look harmless and slow moving. He might even be able to lure a few people away from the crowd by getting them to try and protect or help the "frail old man".

Comment: well ... people are looking everywhere in a crowd, it's not safe to kill someone there, but if you are preparing right you can cause a mass panic, which can easily kill dozen people at the same time. But that doesn't count as melee kill

Comment: @Jannis It depends on the density and size of the crowd for sure. If people are packed in enough then you really can't see a lot happening beneath the surface. Most people are looking over and around.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy people like Johnny usually fall into one of two categories:

- The brutal type who wants some violence. They work in the "Hulk smash" style and usually start violent brawls just to have some fun.
- The silent type who wants to look into their victims eyes as life leaves them. They work in the "Assassins Creed" style and try not to be detected.

If Johnny achieved a high body cound with a melee weapon before, he likely falls into the second category. And now he had 40 years to plan his next killing spree and how exactly he would dodge being detected by authorities.

He would probably start slow and scout for hiding spots. Then he would select single, isolated victims and hide their bodies. Depending on the hiding places he finds, I think he could kill 4 - 6 people before anyone find the first body.

Of course he wouldn't slit anyones throat. That's much too messy and leaves very clear signs behind. Instead, he would stab his victims in a way that kills (or stuns) quickly and causes more internal bleeding than external. Lay people down in a quiet spot, empty half a beer over their groin and leave the bottle in their hands and it takes even longer for people to realize the person is dead instead of drunk.

To prevent a mass panic the police would probably not inform the visitors of the fair. They would send all available units to the fair to try and spot the murderer. Of course Johhny would realize the change.

Now he would have to kill people in riskier places like a toilet stall or behind a booth. He would probably be in more of a hurry to get his body count as high as possible. *Someone* will find a body in the middle of the fair and panic ensures.

This is a good chance for Johnny to hide in the masses. If he follows people running away and has some expression of fear plastered on his face, chances are high the police officers won't spot him. One outside the fair, he can catch panicked and desoriented passerbys and leave a trail of bodies behind.

His actual body count depends on:

- The hideaways available
- His acting skill
- The moment he's spotted by anyone. If he's first spotted by a civilian, he has more time to kill. If it's an officer spotting him first, his time is up.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds awful, but you could go to a school ...
Definetly a school located not in USA. :)
When you arrive just killem. In a class are about 20-30 persons means you can easily make it to your goal. Better kill the janitor first to get the keys to lock the persons. When done, maybe in 1 or two minutes you can even make it to other rooms and kill more children and teacher.
Please don't use this in your story, it's horribly easy to intrude in a school and massacre everyone. I don't want to think for psychopaths.
Hope this helps :/

Comment: If we're talking "kill-effciency-wise", I do think you are proposing a great alternative to reach the goal of 12 kills. However, this scenario happens at night and during a townwide party... So I don't think any schools are open :(

Comment: well if he just waits the night or does some stealth kill, or prepares for the great 'show'  ... I'm getting freakin creeped now

Comment: Yeah... This is a VERY uncomfortable kind of food for thought.